# How can i test to make sure the file name is SpecRunner.html in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

I want to build a test that makes sure the Jasmine Test is using a file called SpecRunner.html".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check window.location (at least if you are running tests in browser).

Quick POC code:

```js
describe("File name", function () {
    it("ends with SpecRunner.html", function () {
        var fileName = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
        expect(window.location.pathname).toMatch(/SpecRunner.html$/);
    });
});
```